# Validating google oauth tokens (youtube.readnonly)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am making a chrome extension than needs to use youtube account information (id as it appears in the link to the channel). I have coped with making `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` give me a token with `"scopes":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]`. It looks like this: `ya29.a0AfH6SMDRpsZf***48VT_yQ4FCsFc8`. Now I have a problem: how to get account info using this token? What request do I have to send to do that?

I have tried the method from here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=your_client_id&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob%3Aauto&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

But my `chrome oauth2 app` in `developer console` does not even have `client_secret`, so it does not seem like my way.

In the `getAuthToken() tutorial` (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/tut_oauth/) they work with google people API and validate it in this way:

```
let init = {
        method: 'GET',
        async: true,
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        'contentType': 'json'
      };
      fetch(
          'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/contactGroups/all?maxMembers=20&key=<API_Key_Here>',
          init)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
          });
```

It works for me if I change scopes to `contacts.readonly` but I need `youtube.readonly` and I do not understand where do I have to send a similar request to get the information I need. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "profile" in scope along with the youtube data api point.

In my chrome extension I am using the gapi to get the information, this includes login and youtube data api to work with youtube videos. This returns the user information in getBasicProfile and authentication information in getAuthResponse.

I have following in my scope
*scope: "email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube openid [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%22)*

Note: You should not use client secret from JS file. Config should only contain client id, apiKey, scope and redirect ui (as per your case).